# Cast nsdata to custom protocol value dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift, casting, protocols, swift-extensions

I have a custom protocol with which I have extended some structures in Swift.

Code example:

```
protocol someprotocol {
  func foo() -> Int
}

extension Int : someprotocol {
 func foo() {
     return 4
     }
}
```

I do this with many structs like int8, int16, float, string etc...

So I have a dictionary of `[Int: someprotocol]` that I want to save as a property of a core data entity. I've tried transformable and nsdata, but the problem is that in both cases the encoded data gets decoded and every `someprotocol` type that is a number is an nsnumber object. So what I read from core data can be downcast to `[int:any]` but not to `[int:someprotocol]`.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE: A piece of code that breaks**

```
 let domainProperties: [Int: someprotocol] = [1:34, 2:Float(48.5), 4:12, 5:"Greg"]

    // Turn this to nsdata. This is how it gets stored in core data
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: domainProperties)

    // This downcast always returns nil. 
    let returnProperties = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [Int: someprotocol]
```

I've seen that the numbers in NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) are stored as NSNumber instances and they can't be downcast to someprotocol.

Comment: Can you add the code that reads back from core data and why can't it be `as? [Int: someprotocol]`?

Comment: Swift automatically boxes its intrinsic types in NSNumber when required; Objective-C APIs, such as NSKeyedArchiver, can't deal with non-object types, so what you are archiving is an NSNumber and that is what you get back when you unarchive.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, I get that. What I am asking is, is there another way to achieve what I want? Store and retrieve the datatype I want

Comment: You would have to use an object, not a protocol, and have that object conform to NSCoding. Or perhaps you could use NSValue?